# How to use libjpeg-turbo to decode JPEG9 Image?

Tags: android, c++, opencv, jpeg

I am using Android 6.0 to do some development. Now I want to use libjpeg-turbo to decode JPEG image(JPEG9 image) taken by the camera in native c++ code. However, libjpeg-turbo can only support JPEG 8. So libjpeg-turbo gives an error as "wrong jpeg library version". Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

In fact, now I am using OpenCV function imdecode to do this job, but it is too slow. Some one says OpenCV uses libjpeg in imdecode and imencode. Is that true?

If I can not use libjpeg-turbo, what else I can use so that JPEG9 image can be decoded and encoded efficiently?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Libjpeg-turbo deliberately does not support images with extensions from libjpeg v9 fork, because they're non-standard and don't offer better compression than images from standard-conforming versions of libjpeg:

https://libjpeg-turbo.org/About/Jpeg-9

So the answer is that you can't decode them. The best you can do is to avoid using libjpeg v9, or if you must, be sure to disable all SmartScale extensions to produce JPEG-compatible files.